# SQL Connection refused with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, connection

I'm aware this can be a recurring question, but none of the solutions i found online seem to be working with my problem.

I have a Laravel 5.8 project but i can't access to my database from a controller, all artisan command works fine (like php artisan migrate)

But when a try a simple thing like:

```
protected function test()
{
   return User::all();
}
```

I get `` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null) ``

I simply trying to access my local database (from OSX)
My Config :

```
.env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

```
database.php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'database'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

My database is working (i can access it with an IDE or else)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have different settings for the connection in your IDE? For example, `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Can you try to execute an insert query from your controller ? If it's working then the user named 'database' in your conf isn't allowed to execute SELECT queries (but can execute INSERT ones, what can explain the succesful migrations), if it's the case, from your mysql prompt, try: 

    GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'database'@'localhost';

Comment: Thanks fo your answer @TravisBritz, i have the same settings in my IDE

Comment: Thanks @MohamedAyoubBENJELLOUN  but same problem for INSERT

Comment: In your database.php file comment the lines containing empty string values (password and unix_socket definitions), do you have the same error ? If yes, change the host or the port value to a wrong one, still get the same error ?

Comment: @GuillaumeProst have you tried changing `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`? This could be a cause if your IDE was getting in through a unix socket for example

Comment: Things that might help narrow down the cause: database name and version, the working connection settings from your IDE, the environment Laravel is running under (docker? MAMP? Homestead?), and as many details you can give about the steps you have tried so far

Comment: So how you solved that issue ?

Comment: @TravisBritz, i tried but same issue

Comment: @Loctarogar i create a docker with mysql and with a different config it works but i didn't found why it didn't work

Comment: Please include the information requested in my last comment in the post if you want to continue looking for the cause. Currently there is not enough information to determine why it works in your IDE but not inside the project.

Answer (score 0):

it isn't the best answer, but create new database user with all privileges and use that user.

Comment: Thanks but same problem, i don't think it is a privileges problem, i have the same issues with root

Comment: if you can work with you database from terminal, but can't from IDE = 99.9% wrong credentials for database in .env file.
My .env file looks like:

`DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=laravel

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=vk3897vk`